# Hibernate валидация таблицы

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

При запуске СпрингБут Хайбер не валидирует колонку в Постгре:

```
phone CHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL
```

несмотря на то, что в энтити выставлено:

```
    @Column(unique=true, nullable = false, name="phone", length=10, columnDefinition = "char")
    private String phone;
```

Что ещё можно тут попробовать?

Ошибка:

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [phone] in table [bankdemo.accounts]; found [bpchar (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [varchar(10) (Types#VARCHAR)]
```

Comment: А что он должен по Вашему валидировать?

Comment: Он фэйлит запуск приложения, требуя, чтобы phone был VARCHAR

Comment: мм, может тогда стоит убрать columnDefinition = "char" в аннотации?

Comment: Я как раз добавил по рекомендациям ENG-SO, т.к. без этого тоже не работало. Но всё равно не помогло. Может ещё какие хитрости есть?

Comment: а что если columnDefinition = "varchar"? Никогда раньше с таким не сталкивался)

Comment: Ну VARCHAR же это колонка произвольной длина ДО -n, а мне нужно строго фиксированной на 10 знаков ни больше ни меньше. При VARCHAR всё ОК, естественно.

Comment: Работает с @Type(type = "char") но это вендор-специфик, а хотелось бы универсальное решение.

Comment: а, ну если условие такое, то может написать brchar?

Comment: Падает с той же ошибкой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
phone VARCHAR(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL 
      CONSTRAINT phonechk CHECK (char_length(phone) = 10)
```